# CiviRules - cannot assign a tag inside a tag tree

Tags: civirules

When I try to add an action to Add a tag that is within a tag tree, none of those "sub-tags" show up. If I have to move all sub-tags that I have up to the top level in order to make this work, this will be a real pain to administer.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that it is a pain. Can you please add this issue to the CiviRules repository at https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues?

Are you able to solve this yourself (do you have PHP skills)? There is documentation on how to add your own condition here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-condition/. Fixing one will follow the same pattern.

If not, the usual community thing comes up:

- if the problem is big for you, it might be worth hiring someone familiar with CiviRules to fix it for you
- if the problem is not big for you wait until it is important to someone else and it is fixed

Comment: Issue added. I have only basic php skills so it would take some time for me to even try to see how I can address it. It's not critical for us at this point, but would definitely be a nice to have moving forward as we create more tag hierarchies. Free form tags don't appear either, but I suspect they are a whole other beast to work with. We're fairly new at CiviCRM and a very small community group with very little funds.

Comment: Okay Rachelle, thanks for adding the issue. I hope it will be interesting enough for someone to pick it up. What do you mean with free form tags?

Comment: You can add tag sets and then add tags on the fly when you're working in CiviCRM. None of those tags are showing up either.

Comment: Okay, I would imagine that is just a case of rebuilding the list. I would imagine they show up the next time you check the rule?

Comment: Nope. Nothing in hierarchies or free form tags ever appear in the rule.

Comment: Weird ;-) Will come up when the issue is processed.